# What do I need to do to set up a Minecraft 1.9 server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Trying to set up a Minecraft 1.9 server; I have had a 1.8 server running before.  I downloaded the server from minecraft.net.  It does not have the same files as before.  [image]

Now what do I do to start the server???

Answer (score 1):

Zip the contents of the folder (but not the folder itself, so select all the files -> right-click -> Send To -> Compressed (Zipped) Folder) and rename the `.zip` to a `.jar`. For some reason you have it unpacked. You can then launch it like you would a 1.8 server.